# Kusto complex json with array

Tags: azure-data-explorer

This is my source format:

```
{
    "message":[
        {"name":"sensorID","value":"5"},
        {"name":"eventT","value":"2021-04-16T19:11:26.149Z"},
        {"name":"pressure","value":"150"}
    ]
}
```

Looking to flatten it out into a table:

| sensorID | eventT | pressure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | "2021-04-16T19:11:26.149Z" | 150 |

Cannot for the life of me figure it out.

Splitting the array just gets me a more nested array:

```
test
| project ray=array_split(message, 1)
```

And using mv-expand gets me two separate rows:

```
test
| mv-expand message
```

At my wits end. any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the schema is unknown in advance, you could try something like this (using `mv-apply`, `summarize make_bag()` and `bag_unpack()`)

```
datatable(d:dynamic)
[
    dynamic({
    "message":[
        {"name":"sensorID","value":"5"},
        {"name":"eventT","value":"2021-04-16T19:11:26.149Z"},
        {"name":"pressure","value":"150"}
    ]}),
        dynamic({
    "message":[
        {"name":"sensorID","value":"55"},
        {"name":"eventT","value":"2021-03-16T19:11:26.149Z"},
        {"name":"pressure","value":"1515"}
    ]})
]
| mv-apply d.message on (
    summarize b = make_bag(pack(tostring(d_message.name), d_message.value))
)
| project b
| evaluate bag_unpack(b)
```

| eventT | pressure | sensorID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-16 19:11:26.1490000 | 1515 | 55 |
| 2021-04-16 19:11:26.1490000 | 150 | 5 |

Comment: This appears to work, now I just need to understand why lol.
`test
| mv-apply message on (
    summarize b = make_bag(pack(tostring(message.name), message.value))
)
| project b
| evaluate bag_unpack(b)`